# How Google IoT Core does the MQTT Load Balancing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, load-balancing, iot, google-cloud-iot

It is not possible to find any references on how Google Actually Load balance the MQTT within their IoT Core.

Is it  MQTT 3.1.1 spec called Shared Subscriptions which allow multiple clients to consume messages in a distributed fashion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will not be using an off the shelf broker, it will be entirely custom code that they can make do anything they want to distribute messages within their infrastructure.

As long as it accepts and responds to the MQTT protocol messages to/from remote devices, it doesn't matter what it does internally.